# How to store flash object in different location

Tags: asp.net, flash, cookies, actionscript

How to store flash objects in different location?

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Guys! any one help me for this

Comment: we don't understand what you're asking. What kind of object are you talking about. What location is it in now. and where are you trying to get it to...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not quite sure what you're asking, I think you're looking for the ApplicationDomain class (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html).  Once you've partitioned your program into different SWFs, you can load those SWFs (ostensibly containing class definitions) into different Application Domains by setting the LoaderContext (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html) property on Loader.load(url_request, application_domain).  Here are some cool resources on ApplicationDomain:

http://code.google.com/p/maashaack/wiki/ApplicationDomain
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/

and there is also SharedObject, if you're thinking of 'Flash cookies' (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

Buut if you're talking about serializing Flash objects (a la Memento pattern), there are a couple of built in ways to do it:

- Export the Object as XML using describeType ([http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29)), with code like this: http://ria.dzone.com/news/automatic-serialization, or by just writing your own custom serialize/deserialize methods.
- Export the Object as JSON (using a JSON library , or with Flash Player 11's new JSON.stringify, for instance: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#stringify()

Does that answer your question?

**Upate after clarification (comment):**

I still don't know what you're asking - can you be more explicit?  If you're looking to use Flash cookies, then check out the SharedObject reference above.  If you're trying to explicitly control where specific objects are stored the memory allocator of the AVM, then there is no way to do that.  The closest you can get is controlling where the class *definitions* are stored (see ApplicationDomain and LoaderContext references above).

Please let me know if that doesn't answer your question.

**Final update after (final) clarification:**

Definitely not possible to change where Flash Player stores SharedObjects, as it would present a significant security risk. The storage location is completely determined by Flash Player and not editable by the developer for very good reason. Consider the havoc a web app could wreak by writing to or reading from any location on the end user's system.

The closest you could get is (in an AIR application only) serializing (AMF or other means) the objects and writing/reading them using the File and FileStream classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.make it crisp is it possible to change the storing location. i have done everything with in my flash object.

Comment: Per user978122 and Chris Burt-Brown's comments, can you be more specific?  Did my edit answer your question?  Is Action Message Format what you're looking for, perhaps? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format

Comment: generally Flash cookies saved in "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects" at the client end right? i know you knew this... what my question is can we store this shared object c:\ in a folder? and confirm me we can get a access of it?